# Can't switch to wireless mode

Tags: release-loki, settings, wifi

Some days ago I install on my PC elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki with parallel Win 8.1.

But I have a trouble. When start elementary OS, I have only wired connection and can't switch it on wireless. The slider doesn't respond.

Write this from Win 8.1 with connection to WiFi.

Comment: Can you open System Settings, go to Network and turn wireless on from there? Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Steps to produce

1. Find your wifi driver over Google (or whatever search engine you prefer)
2. inside the source direct, make and install the drivers.

Reason : This is a restricted feature on NT kernel, which basically hijack propreatery drivers regardless of System shutdowns.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm noob. I have broadcom 802.11n.
Ok. I find driver. Download it with instruction. Do all step-by-step but something going wrong with wl.ko. Terminal writing smth like wl.ko does not exist or is not the right way.

Comment: Post the output of "ipconfig"